# TypeScript infer generic type of T in Inner<T> for Outer<T>

Tags: typescript, oop, generics

I have an `Inner<T>` interface that wraps a value of a generic type:

```js
interface Inner<T> {
    v: T;
}
```

There are different implementations of that Interface:

```js
class SomeInner<T> implements Inner<T> {
    constructor(public v: T) {}
    some = true;
}

class SomeOtherInner<T> implements Inner<T> {
    constructor(public v: T) {}
    someOther = true;
}
```

There is an `Outer` class that wraps an instance of `Inner<T>`. I also want to access Inner from time to time. Therefore I keep the actual type of Inner:

```js
class Outer<T, TInner extends Inner<T>> {
    constructor(public inner: TInner) { }
    getV(): T {
        return this.inner.v;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately TS is not able to infer the type of T in Outer - although it knows the type of TInner and its generic type:

```js
const someInnerInst = new SomeInner("foo" as string);
const outerInstOfSomeInner = new Outer(someInnerInst);

const vFromOuter = outerInstOfSomeInner.getV(); // Type: unknown // <- SHOULD BE string
const vFromInner = outerInstOfSomeInner.inner.v; // Type: string
```

Is there a way to help TypeScript to infer T in Outer?

You can try the [full example in the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=65&pln=21&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIhNAPAFQHzIDeAsAFACQAbgFzI4DcZAvmWQgDZwDOXyAygHsAthHSYouAsCEAHdhBHheY7PiJlyCASC5goAVwRgBUABQz9AI3bAEyGnQCURFhS7CUAXmR79ERqSuHNy8giIA8mAAFtAqEmrScgoQSmgYqgQkFFo6vkYm5lY2dg44zoSu5O4R0dDI3r7%20zKykwTzI4fqQ8QA0dHHIEAAekCAAJsrp8XiZGjm6BvlmFta2yKDitDhx5eSVAOYQYABqpo5b6hTkUEf6UCA%20UcBcAHQb0C%20UAXvNpC3zYGQ1VEU3QunqyEwAHd%20B44qYAEQwAQCBHIbhAvSgfaOAIA5ACLqxXLhGBhEHiCHQjpEszAuJgsC4-7acGUABiUGEnW6EMJ3UZpPJcRehxOZ3oyAA9FK6ABPGQQWj6EAAaxAAihIDYrMBHK5QgG3n5xN0QrhUzelq%200tlOAVSsxUGxQA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript will not infer `T` from the other type parameter. Basically since `T` does not appear in the parameter list of the constructor no inference will occur for it. You can go about solving this in several ways.

One of the simplest would be to use an intersection to give typescript an inference site for `T` in the constructor:

```
class Outer<TInner extends Inner<T>, T> {
    constructor(public inner: TInner & Inner<T>) {  }
    getV(): T {
        return this.inner.v;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIhNAPAFQHzIDeAsAFACQAbgFzI4DcZAvmWQgDZwDOXyAygHsAthHSYouAsCEAHdhBHheY7PiJlyCASC5goAVwRgBUABQz9AI3bAEyGnQCURFhS7CUAXmR79ERqSuHNy8giIA8mAAFtAqEmrScgoQSmgYqgQkFFo6vkYm5lY2dg44zoSu5O4R0dDI3r7+zKykwTzI4fqQ8XHIEAAekCAAJsrp8XgANHSZGjm6BvlmFta2yKDitDi9AGRp4pLl5JUA5hBgAGqmjlvqFORQ5-pQID5RwFwAdBvQn5QBx2apBa8zAyGqonG6F09WQmAA7vwPHFTAAiGACASo5DccF6UAnRwBUHIARdWK5cIwMKQ8SwhEdclmCFxaFgIkg7QwygAMSgwk63VhZO6bKpNLinzOl2u9GQAHp5XQAJ4yCC0BYEthcsG8-lCXreEUU3Ti5Hjb4W-4KpU4VXqvFQAlAA)

You could also use some form of relative typing to extract `T` from `TInner`, for example index access types:

```
class Outer<TInner extends Inner<any>> {
    constructor(public inner: TInner) { }
    getV(): TInner['v'] {
        return this.inner.v;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Or with conditional types:

```
type InnerTypeParam<T extends Inner<any>> = T extends Inner<infer U> ? U : never

class Outer<TInner extends Inner<any>> {
    constructor(public inner: TInner) { }
    getV(): InnerTypeParam<TInner> {
        return this.inner.v;
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIhNAPAFQHzIDeAsAFACQAbgFzI4DcZAvmWQgDZwDOXyAygHsAthHSYouAsCEAHdhBHheY7PiJlyCASC5goAVwRgBUABQz9AI3bAEyGnQCURFhS7CUAXmR79ERqSuHNy8giIA8mAAFtAqEmrScgoQSmgYqgQkFFo6vkYm5lY2dg44zoSu5O4R0dDI3r7+zKykYACeMihxOB0QAApwUHBCuMgQAB6QIAAmyukScCBteATeOGOTKbNp4ligMHUAqgQA-MiHyLSYlNAtwTzI4fqQ8XEbU9txWIvLmRo5ugM+TMFmstmQoHEtBwcXK5EqAHMIGAAGqmRy0bq9AZDEYw+Z-CjkKDI-RQEA+KLALgAOkh0BplAC8OapDu2l0yGqonm6E53kwAHd+B44qYAEQwAQCcXIbhcvSgBGOAIAsDIATPWK5cIwMI88T1ZBCx5aszcuJ8sAq9m5ewAMSgwieLyNmpeVt1+riNKRqPR9GQAHog3RerR9CAANYgASCkBsDnqyiO4Rvbzu7W6L2i+Z0vNM4OhnqdWiApVAA)

Comment: Uh I was a little too fast. The type `Outer<SomeInner<string>, string>` is a really redundant. Is there a way get rid of the extra string?

Comment: @htho You can use the other versions. I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks again. By changing the type Parameters to `<TInner extends Inner<any>, T = InnerTypeParam<TInner>>` I could use `getV(): T {...}` again. This declaration is also valid with an optional Type Parameter: `const checkOuter: Outer<SomeInner<string>> = outerInstOfSomeInner;` (Playground link won't fit the comments.) Feel Free to add that to your Answer.

Comment: @htho I've found out, that you can use `T` instead of `any` in `<TInner extends Inner<any>, T = InnerTypeParam<TInner>>`, and that should give better type annotations when working with `inner` inside the class.